# Simple basic calculator in java code academy

Tags: java

I just learned how to use classes and constructors but Idk why my code isn't running. Said illegal start, but I'm positive that it is right. I also looked at other people's code and they are the same as what I put. Can someone look at what is wrong

```
public class Calculator{//basic calculator

public Calculator(){

    public int add(int a, int b){
      return a+b;
    }
    public int subtract(int a, int b){
      return a-b;
    }
    public int multiply(int a, int b){
      return a*b;
    }
    public int divide(int a, int b){
      if(b==0){
       System.out.println("Error! Dividing by zero is not allowed.");
        return 0;
      }else{
          return a/b;
      }
    }
    public int modulo(int a, int b){
      if(b==0){
       System.out.println("Error! Dividing by zero is not allowed.");
        return 0;
      }else{
          return a%b;
      }
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args) {
   Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();
   System.out.println(myCalculator.add(5, 7));
   System.out.println(myCalculator.subtract(12, 34));
 }


  }
```

Comment: Simple typos, one too many ending curly braces for the `modulo` method - delete one, fix your constructor - should not have nest methods, also your `divide` method will only do integer division

Comment: *but I'm positive that it is right* Don't ever be positive your code is right

Comment: The compiler is telling you that it's wrong -- believe it

Comment: You've got a constructor with seemingly class-level method definitions. Not valid Java.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Remove `public Calculator() {` that line does nothing.</s>

EDIT: Actually at second glance it looks like that line was an attempted constructor but you wrapped the entire classes contents in the brackets `{}`. This should work:

```
public class Calculator {//basic calculator

    public Calculator() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();
        System.out.println(myCalculator.add(5, 7));
        System.out.println(myCalculator.subtract(12, 34));
    }


    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int subtract(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    public int multiply(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    public int divide(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error! Dividing by zero is not allowed.");
            return 0;
        } else {
            return a / b;
        }
    }

    public int modulo(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error! Dividing by zero is not allowed.");
            return 0;
        } else {
            return a % b;
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT #2: As Wombat pointed out (one of my least favorite Java features because of how much time I've spent troubleshooting) is that `a / b` is integer division and will (practically) never give you the result you need. Also, your method returns `int` which was probably not your intention. So your divide method should use `double`:

```
public double divide(double a, double b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error! Dividing by zero is not allowed.");
        return 0;
    } else {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

Comment: *divide method will only do integer division* `1/3 == 0`

Comment: thanks so much, was close shouldn't have wrap the constructor in a new method